# To find a trigonometric limit without Wallis' integrals

Tags: limits, trigonometry

What is the limit $$ \lambda =\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}{n\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\sin x)^{2n} dx}$$ I would like to find it without  [Wallis' integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals) formula: I mean without evaluating the closed form. Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: I didn't look too deep, did you try the induction on $n$? I mean take $\sin^{2n} x = \sin x \sin^{2n-1}x$, integrate by parts, etc.

Comment: @Alex I thought about it but got stuck. Thanks.

Comment: how did you do it? Define $I_n = n \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^{2n}x dx$, do the IBP. You should see the pattern.

Comment: @Alex but that's reinventing the Wallis wheel, and I don't really understand why te OP wants to do without it, since it's so simple.

Comment: OK I admit I never heard of Wallis integral before. Induction+IBS seem like a logical choice for this problem.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut My point is can we find it without Stirling's formula? That's why I ask if it is possible.

Comment: Since the limits of integration remain the same, try examining how the integrand $n \sin^{2n}x$ behaves as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: @Alex It's the classical way to obtain a recurrence, then a closed form for the above integral, using one binomial coefficient and a simple factor, depending on parity of $n$. Then it's very easy to get an asymptotic equivalent of 2n choose n, and it can be used to derive Stirling's approximation. But, well before getting that far, you have the recurrence and the closed form. Well, the OP should know at least this, since he's talking about Wallis in the first place.

Comment: @event Write the recurrence. Wallis integral is not Stirling approximation! (have you actually read the Wiki article you point to ???) And you won't even have to deal with parity, since you have only the even exponent case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\sin x)^{2n}dx=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\cos x)^{2n}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}e^{-n f(x)}dx,
$$
where $f(x)=-2\log\cos x$.  As $n\rightarrow \infty$, the integral is dominated by the region around $x=0$, since that is the unique minimum of $f(x)$.  But for small $x$ we have
$$
f(x)=-2\log\cos x \approx -2\log(1-x^2/2)\approx x^2.
$$
So
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\sin x)^{2n}dx \;\sim\; \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-nx^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{n}}
$$
as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: How can I not upvote the Laplace method?

Comment: @mjqxxxx Thanks!